# Equivalence between the two definitions of NEXPTIME complexity class

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEXPTIME) gives two definitions for the NEXP complexity class:

1. $
   \mathsf{NEXPTIME} = \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \mathsf{NTIME}(2^{n^k})
   $

where $\mathsf{NTIME}(f(n))$ is the set of decision problems that can be solved by a non-deterministic Turing machine which runs in time $O(f(n))$.

2. Using deterministic Turing machines as verifiers. A formal language ''L'' is in '''NEXPTIME''' if and only if there exist polynomials ''p'' and ''q'', and a deterministic Turing machine ''M'', such that

   - For all ''x'' and ''y'', the machine ''M'' runs in time $2^{p(|x|)}$ on input $(x,y)$
   - For all ''x'' in ''L'', there exists a string ''y'' of length $2^{q(|x|)}$ such that $M(x,y) = 1$
   - For all ''x'' not in ''L'' and all strings ''y'' of length $2^{q(|x|)}$, $M(x,y) = 0$

Is it obvious to see why these two definitions are equivalent? (if not, any way to prove they are equivalent?)

Comment: How do you define ​ NTIME(2^(n^k)) ? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Updated the definitions.

Comment: Do you already have the corresponding equivalence for the two definitions of NP? ​ ​

Comment: No, that's my question. But it's sorta implied by the Wikipage of NEXP.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)#Equivalence_of_definitions ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer thanks for pointing out the equivalence of the definitions with NDTM and DTM. Unless I'm missing anything, the same proof should apply here too.

Comment: Well, they're not equivalent when there's a space bound, since in that case that verifier won't necessarily have room to store the whole certificate. ​ (To recover equivalence, one needs to restrict the verifiers to just _one-way_ access to the alleged-proof.) ​ Also, if the TM only has [one head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitape_Turing_machine), then simulating non-determinism via a certificate can multiply runtime by O(space usage + certificate length). ​ ​ ​ ​